# Send raw request via Postman

Tags: postman

Postman delivers UI to do stuff but is there a way to send a raw request like

```
GET / HTTP1.1
Host: my-host
```

I would like to train doing it manually and I know that for example a software like Burb Suite with its Repeater delivers such function.

Comment: I have not found anything in Postman which allows me to send a raw HTTP request. I'd love to see one, or even just the ability to parse a raw HTTP request into a new Postman request. Short of using HTTP debuggers like Fiddler, Charles, or ZAP, you could always ask Postman for this feature.

Answer (score -1):

use dothttp. it is more like programing.

checkout https://docs.dothttp.dev/docs/request-basics